# Integrating Swift in Rails

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift

As the Title says, I'm having trouble understanding how this is done (I am very new to swift). Based on what I read, it sounds like Swift is acting like a front-end language for a mobile device yet when an action happens involving the database, a get or post request is made to interact with the rails backend somehow then using that information to visually update the swift app? In other words, I'm lost on the responsibilities of swift when pairing it with rails. All advice welcome!

Note, I'm trying to follow and understand this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/85528/user-accounts-ios-ruby-rails-swift

Comment: The responsibility you already know is to access your api get the json string parse it and display to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like many gui based apps, most iOS apps follow the MVC (Model View Controller) pattern.  In the case of an app integrated with a rails app, the rails app would serve as the model, accessed via the network.

The rails app itself is an MVC based app, but unlike a traditional rails app which would return html to a browser, the view that is returned would be some sort of a data object that would be used by the requesting mobile app as the model in it's MVC.  In most modern cases the data object would be a json object.

This is the same concept used in modern web apps, such as Angular 2, were the javascript app acts as a front end to a backend server app that returns json objects which act as the models in the Angular 2 MVC.

Looking at it this way, you end up with the concept of a backend server that responds to requests from any number of front ends, Android written in Java, iOS written in Swift, or Angular,Ember,etc, written in javascript, etc.  The rails app only has to respond with json which each of the requesting front end apps, then use as models in there own MVC which display the model data and interact with the user.

Hope this helps.